Update a Column of a Matrix where each MongoDB document is a Row
I'm storing matrices in MongoDB where each document is a row of values. Example of two small matrices but assume there are thousands of rows and columns:
[
  { matrix_id: 123, row_id: 0, values: [1, 2, 3] },
  { matrix_id: 123, row_id: 1, values: [4, 5, 6] },
  { matrix_id: 789, row_id: 0, values: [20, 40, 60] },
  { matrix_id: 789, row_id: 1, values: [80, 100, 120] }
]

(It can't be in just one document with all the rows and columns because it would exceed the 16 MB size limit. If I use GridFS then I can't update single values, full rows, or full columns efficiently.)
Say I want to update the full 2nd column (index=1) of matrix 123 to have the values [7890, 9876] and get a result like this:
┌       ┐    ┌          ┐
│ 1 2 3 │ ─→ │ 1 7890 3 │
│ 4 5 6 │    │ 4 9876 6 │
└       ┘    └          ┘

then this updateOne() query - to update a single value - is being reused to update full columns, so is executed for each row document. Mongo Playground. I'm repeating this with different params for row_id & new_col_val:
db.collection.update({
  matrix_id: 1,
  // index of the row being updated
  row_id: 0
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      values: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            // index of the column being updated
            col_idx: 1,
            // value for that column being updated
            new_col_val: 7890
          },
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              { $slice: ["$values", "$$col_idx"] },
              ["$$new_col_val"],
              { $slice: ["$values", { $add: ["$$col_idx", 1] }, { $size: "$values" }] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

To do all full-column updates, I put this in a function in the app's language and keep updating the row_id & column value; but that's quite inefficient, including using Bulk Write ops:
def update_column(col_idx: int, values: list[int]):
    # using find_one_and_update / update_one
    for row_idx, col_val in enumerate(values):
        update = update_action(col_idx, col_val)  # returns above query with col_idx & col_val
        collection.update_one({"matrix_id": 1, "row_id": row_idx}, update)
    
    # using bulk_write
    requests = [
      UpdateOne({"matrix_id": 1, "row_id": row_idx}, update_action(col_idx, col_val))
      for row_idx, col_val in enumerate(values)
    ]
    result = collection.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)  # parallel execution

Is there a better way with fewer total statements/queries or reduce total time? Or just something cleaner?
PS. I'm not actually doing this, was exploring another user's question.

Weird use case to me. Maybe store each individual matrix element as a single document with row_index and col_index and indexing the 2 fields...? From my understandings you are trying to access the matrix by row and col anyway

@ray To me, storing every element in separate documents and accessing with matrix_id, row_id, col_id would be standard SQL pattern. I would say putting the data as rows (or columns) means certain operations are faster.  So for a 4000 x 3000 matrix, getting all the elements (even in an aggregation) would require 12,000,000 documents to be accessed and combined, all on the DB side sure. When stored by rows (or columns), that comes down to 4000 (or 3000) documents. Example aggregation.

So there is an aspect of 'matrix size' & access patterns dictating the design, rather than a 'any-size will work', which the one-element-per-document pattern would support. If the matrices were suddenly going to be 4 million rows x 4 million columns, then I would have to split it per element since 4 million 32-bit int's hits the 16 MB limit. Otoh, if the matrixes were all going to be max ~100x100, then storing the whole thing in one document would be ideal.

These are all reasonable and detailed considerations. If the size of the matrix is still manageable, maybe store the row elements as objects to indicate their col_index like this...? An index on mat_id, row_id, values.col_id can still be leveraged. Actually, I am still confused about the usage of such a matrix operation use case in MongoDB. It looks to me that the original poster should opt for the usage of RDBMS if they need to work on such a big matrix from time to time.

Nice, I was considering doing row values with the col_id + value as an object as you have done values: [ { col_id: 0, value: 1 }, { col_id: 1, value: 2 }, ... ] but it felt excessive; I'm 50-50 on that. However, your col-objects definitely makes insert/update queries much easier/faster . In general, I would agree that the OP should go with the RDBMS option for this (SO post, DBA post) - but that lacks the benefit of any quick operations for row/column updates.

Both our schemas give either fast-full-row updates OR fast-full-column updates. In RDBMS, neither is possible. Those updates would need to use the elem-at-index method. Even having column-values-in-columns is not fully possible (and begs to be normalised) since PostgreSQL has 1600 column limit. MySQL allows for 4096 columns with a 64KB row size limit, so that would fit (ugly). But the correct RDBMS normalised form of (matrix_id, row_id, col_id, value) would require massive read ops even for just one matrix. RDBMS 9 mil recs vs NoSQL 3,000 docs. On the same hardware, I think NoSQL is faster.

The hint to optimise this comes from two places:

The use of enumerate() which fetches each item with its index

Translates roughly to using $arrayElemAt


The list of values for updating a column has to have the same size as the number of rows

And each row starts at idx=0 and is presumably sequential



Combining that, use updateMany with just the matrix_id and fetch each element of the new column values list corresponding to the row index. (Or row index + 1 if they start at 1.)
So it would require just one updateMany statement which can be passed in the full list of values for the column and the column index:
db.collection.update({ matrix_id: 1 },
[
  {
    $set: {
      values: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            // index of the column being updated
            col_idx: 1,
            // the full replacement column
            new_col: [7890, 9876]
          },
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              { $slice: ["$values", "$$col_idx"] },
              [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$new_col", "$row_id"] }],
              { $slice: ["$values", { $add: ["$$col_idx", 1] }, { $size: "$values" }] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)

Mongo Playground
And the Python code is now trivially just that one statement, no loops/bulk actions required:
def update_column(col_idx: int, values: list[int]):
    result = collection.update_many({"matrix_id": 1}, update_action(col_idx, values))

Btw, use the let parameter of update_many() to pass in the column index and values, and remove the $let from the Python version of the update:
def update_column(col_idx: int, values: list[int]):
    update = [
        {
            "$set": {
                "values": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                        {"$slice": ["$values", "$$col_idx"]},
                        [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$$new_col", "$row_id"]}],
                        {"$slice": ["$values", {"$add": ["$$col_idx", 1]}, {"$size": "$values"}]},
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    result = collection.update_many({"matrix_id": 1}, update, let={"col_idx": 1, "new_col": [7890, 9876]})

